# MvvmCross + Fragments + Back Button = Crash or controls not responding / bound

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, mvvmcross

**EDIT**
I originally was asking 2 questions as one and it wasn't clear, I'm editing it to focus on the more important issue.

I have an application that is using a DrawerLayout as the FirstView (MvxFragmentActivity), and click the menu items on the drawer causes the content of the activity to switch to the associated Fragment (MvxFragment).  In one of the fragments, I have a Google Map that displays markers for information sites.  Everything works fine when the app first launches, or if I uses the menu to navigate.  But if I switch fragments, to say the company information page, and then hit the hardware back button (When each fragment is loaded, I call fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack), and then try adding pins to the map, it does not actually add the pins.  From the digging I have been able to do, it seems that it is putting a duplicate layout into the fragment and I'm binding to the wrong one (the BindingInflate seems to be putting the duplicates). Here is my code:

FirstView.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<Mvx.MvxListView
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MenuItems; ItemClick SelectMenuItemCommand"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/drawer_menu_item"
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_background" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MapView.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_map" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FirstView.cs (relevent parts anyways, based on MvxFragmentActivity demo from MvvmCross github):

```
    public bool Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        Mvx.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic, "FirstView Show: {0}", request.ViewModelType.Name);
        var title = string.Empty;
        var section = ViewModelMapper.GetSectionForViewModel(request.ViewModelType);
        var fragType = ViewMapper.GetViewTypeForSection(section);
        if (IsCurrentFragmentTheGivenType(fragType))
        {
            return true;
        }

        title = GetFragmentTitle(section);

        MvxFragment frag = (MvxFragment)Activator.CreateInstance(fragType);
        var loaderService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewModelLoader>();
        var viewModel = loaderService.LoadViewModel(request, null /* saved state */);

        frag.ViewModel = viewModel;

        var fragTrans = this.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragTrans.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, frag);
        if (!firstTime)
        {
            fragTrans.AddToBackStack(section.ToString());
        }
        fragTrans.SetTransition((int)FragmentTransit.FragmentOpen);
        fragTrans.Commit();

        return true;
    }
```

and in my MapView fragment code:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var view = this.BindingInflate(layoutId, null);
    this.mapView = view.FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.main_map);
    mapView.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    var map = mapView.Map;
    map.UiSettings.MyLocationButtonEnabled = true;
    map.MyLocationEnabled = true;
}
```

I have tried it both with and without `this.RetainInstance = true;` and to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT  Added example code below original answer**

I'm not sure you have this set up right.  Is your overall project flow setup like this [example?](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/3fb27dfc5f59a10ca3bbe9a0e2b70f4ecd09711c/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/TabView.cs)

The general set up is that each tab is its own view model.  I have this up and running in my own project and have not had any issues with bindings not working.  It also sounds like you are not handling the back button properly.  If your mapView is its own tab, hitting the "back" button should exit the app not take you to a different tab.

Here is an example of my setup main tab setup:

MainView.cs

```
public class MainView : MvxTabsFragmentActivity
{
    public MainViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get { return (MainViewModel)ViewModel; }
    }

    public MainView() 
        : base(Resource.Layout.MainView, Resource.Id.actualtabcontent)
    {
    }

    protected override void AddTabs(Bundle args)
    {
        AddTab<TabView1>("Tab1", "Tab 1", args, MainViewModel.TabViewModel1);
        AddTab<TabView2>("Tab2", "Tab 2", args, MainViewModel.TabViewModel2);
        AddTab<TabView3>("Tab3", "Tab 3", args, MainViewModel.TabViewModel3);
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public BaseViewModel TabViewModel1 { get; set; }
    public BaseViewModel TabViewModel2 { get; set; }
    public BaseViewModel TabViewModel3 { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        TabViewModel1 = Mvx.IocConstruct<TabViewModel1>();
        TabViewModel2 = Mvx.IocConstruct<TabViewModel2>();
        TabViewModel3 = Mvx.IocConstruct<TabViewModel3>();
    }
}
```

MainView.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/actualtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

TabView1.cs

```
public class TabView1 : MvxFragment
{

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.TabViewOne, null);
    }
}
```

With this setup I do not lose any binding or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I am using that example.  But now that I look at the question, I'm not very clear.  I will try to make it better.

Comment: It does not seem like you are doing this the "easy" way.  It looks like you are doing Android specific code instead of working through MvvmCross.  For instance where is your "Show" command being called from?  What happens if you doing fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack?  Does this work if you just go to a different tab and then come back to the map view?

Comment: Switching tabs causes the OnCreateView to be called again, and it stops working right.  (I have a series of buttons on one of the tabs that I turn on/off based on settings, but they start as visible, and when I come back to the tab, I cannot turn them on/off anymore)

Comment: I should also state, that there are really 2 issues, both related to fragments.  The first is having a single activity that hosts multiple fragments (a V4.DrawerLayout) and the second is an MvxTabsFragmentActivity with 4 fragments as the tab content.  Both suffer from the same problem that if the MvxFragment's OnCreateView is called again and the BundleInflate method is called, that everything stops working as expected.

Comment: That is not the experience I've had using MvxTabsFragmentActivity.  I'm going to edit my answer above with some code of how I've implemented this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, found the answer to my own question.  In an MvxFragment.OnCreateView (or even the OnViewCreated), I was doing:

```
var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
var view = this.BindingInflate(layoutId, null);
contactBox = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.preserve_contact_box);
```

and was then attempting to use the contactBox field elsewhere in my code.  That does not work.

If on the other hand, I wait until later in the code (this example is from inside an event handler):

```
contactBox = this.View.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.preserve_contact_box);
```

then the contactBox is linked to the correct view on the form and works as expected.